# Why does my mouse skip during network traffic?

Tags: windows, mouse

I have a Microsoft Arc Touch mouse with its own wireless dongle, but my issue has happened to me on a couple of other wireless mice as well. Whenever I access the network (i.e. copy files across a local network, download files from the web, etc.) my mouse gets laggy/skippy.

The heavier the network access the worse it is. I've tried moving the dongle around in case it's interference, but that hasn't helped. Any ideas? I am using Windows 7 currently.

Answer (score 2):

Your mouse could be using the same wireless frequency of your wireless router. Try changing the router wireless channel.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I can't. I'm in a corporate environment and we have a number of routers. I currently have the exact same mouse at home and at work. At work I don't know the router manufacturer, but at home I have a NetGear. I'll try to look up the frequencies. Aren't router frequencies predetermined by the technology (802.11n for instance)?

Comment: I am not using wireless and the problem still exists. Any ideas?